# Set barrier dismissible after dialog shown

Tags: flutter, dialog

This is the way I normally set the dialog's `barrierDismissible` field to true or false

```dart
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: ...
)
```

However, it implies that dialog is ALWAYS true or false.

Is there any way to start a dialog `barrierDismissible` as **false** and change it to **true** after one second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like flutter declarative approach wasn't applied to this widget. Therefore you should do everything yourself.

First handle yourself the tap with:

- A general gesture detector which will be used to dismiss the dialog.
- A gesture detector around your dialog in order to prevent the tap event to bubble up if it happened in the widget inside your dialog.

Second use a variable to state if the `barrierDismissible` should be activated or not, and modify this variable after 1 second. This is the variable which should be used be the general gesture detector in order to know if it should dismiss the dialog or not.

Here is a quick exemple, just tap the FAB:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        home: MyApp(),
      ),
    );

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool barrierDismissible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              barrierDismissible = false;
              Future.delayed(
                  Duration(seconds: 1),
                  () => setState(() {
                        barrierDismissible = true;
                      }));
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  if (barrierDismissible) {
                    Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
                  }
                },
                child: Material(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Center(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 200,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

create bool variable and set that to the barrierDismissible property and use Future.delayed(duration:Duration(seconds:1)) to mak one second count then when the counter completes set the variable to true like this.

```
onPressed:(){
bool dismissible=false;
showDialog(context: context,barrierDismissible: dismissible); //add your child
        Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).whenComplete(() {

          setState(() {
            dismissible=true;
          });
        });

}
```

Comment: Did you test your solution? This does not work for me.

Comment: This would start a new dialog after 1 second, and not even close the old one.

Comment: You should read documentation about how setState works and how states are handled in general in Flutter. 

This code will do nothing more than launching a dialog with an undismissible barrier and then updating a variable that is no longer in use.